# How to reference HTML meta tags in a template engine?

Tags: html, markdown, jekyll, liquid, static-site

I'm using Jekyll to build a static site for my blog site. Jekyll uses the liquid template engine.

To reference posts (blog posts) in the `_posts` directory, the code in the `index.html` is something like this

```html
<ul class="posts">

    {% for post in site.posts %}
    <!-- do stuff here -->

    <div class="container">
       <h4 class="card-title"><b>{{ post.title }}</b></h4>
       <p class="card-author">{{ post.author }}</p>
    </div>
    {% endif %}

</ul>
```

Sample markdown file (`.md`) in `_posts`:

```
---
layout: default
title:  "Another Blog Post!"
date:   2021-08-09 00:00:00
cover_image: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sharmaabhishekk/sharmaabhishekk.github.io/master/images/cover.png"
categories: main
tag: "advanced"
author: "Abhishek Sharma"
---
Hi this is a blog post!

Jekyll offers powerful support for code snippets:

{% highlight ruby %}
def print_hi(name)
  puts "Hi, #{name}"
end
print_hi('Tom')
#=> prints 'Hi, Tom' to STDOUT.
{% endhighlight %}
```

For each of the `markdown` files in my `_posts` directory, it iterates over it and displays it appropriately. More importantly, I can use the `post.<attribute>` way to refer to variables I set (post.title, post.author) in the markdown file.

**However, I'd like to write my posts in `HTML` and not markdown. I want to know how can I still**

1. ***how to iterate over the `.html` files in my `_posts` directory?***
2. ***how to define these values in my html file?***
3. ***how can the template engine parse through and read those variables?***

For 2.), I settled on a way to use `meta` tags to write those values. I'm not sure if that's best practice but this is what I'm doing.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  
  <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Site Title</title>
  <meta name="author" content="Abhishek Sharma">
  <meta name="title" content="Blog Post 1">
  <meta name="date" content="10-08-2021">

</head>
```

***But then I'm unsure how to reference these meta tag name and content pairs in my `index.html` liquid template.***

I'd appreciate any help with this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use HTML files as post or collection items in Jekyll by default:

1. Rename `_posts/2020-01-01-example.md` to `_posts/2020-01-01-example.html`
2. Change the content to HTML (keep the front matter the same)

You'll iterate over them the same way (with `site.posts`), and you'll be able to access the front matter as you were.

Here's what your example file would look like (the `DOCTYPE` and other tags you reference are in your default layout):

```html
---
layout: default
title:  "Another Blog Post!"
date:   2021-08-09 00:00:00
cover_image: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sharmaabhishekk/sharmaabhishekk.github.io/master/images/cover.png"
categories: main
tag: "advanced"
author: "Abhishek Sharma"
---
<p>Hi this is a blog post!</p>

<p>Jekyll offers powerful support for code snippets:</p>

{% highlight ruby %}
def print_hi(name)
  puts "Hi, #{name}"
end
print_hi('Tom')
#=> prints 'Hi, Tom' to STDOUT.
{% endhighlight %}
```

Comment: Your solution proved very helpful, thank you :) I've accepted the answer, cheers!